# How to undo downvotes or report self for abuse?

Tags: support, abuse

So the last 5 downvotes I gave out were not warranted and given in a moment of Internet weakness.  (I just have a pet peeve against people who ask a question then snarkily reply that the answer you took time to give 'makes their skin crawl'.) But in any case it was abuse, and I don't mind losing some rep, but I am unable to reverse what I did.  (It says I can only change my vote if the answer has been edited).  Is there a way to report abuse (it is pretty clear cut since I am admitting to it) and having a moderator take care of it?

Comment: Apologize so this doesn't get out of hand.  Move on.

Comment: The votes would be undone at night by our vote pattern script that detects things like this...but I went ahead and invalidated these votes immediately to resolve this quicker.

Comment: @Nick: that should probably be an answer?

Comment: +1, I appreciate you resolving this in a mature manner. There is a lot to be said for your actions here; way more than I can say on behalf of some other the other conduct I've experienced here on StackOverflow. Cheers, mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderators can't change votes, although I suppose they could edit the posts in question to allow you to modify your vote yourself. Ultimately, it's probably not worth the effort. So long as you learn your lesson and consider your downvotes more carefully in the future, it's all good.

That said, I think downvoting a question or answer that you think is worded aggressively is not necessarily a bad thing. "Be nice" is one of the guidelines clearly states in the FAQ. If someone can't be bothered to be nice to those helping them, do they deserve the upvotes?

Comment: Thing is, in this example: the OP [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328760/display-link-in-rails-form-error-message/5330551#5330551), and *felt* received a "snarky" comment from the question asker. In such case, there's really no related post to downvote. Flagging the comment could have done the trick though; if a few others agree and flag as well, then things will be resolved just nicely (without any reputation penalty for the commenter). If not, problem solved too!

Comment: @Arjan Ah, fair point. I misread the post. Thanks.